# Reference for $e^{x-x^2/2a} \le 1+ ax$

Tags: inequality, reference-request

I am pretty sure $e^{x-x^2/2a} \le 1+ ax$ for every $x\ge 0$ and $a \ge 1$ but cannot see how to prove it.

[Here is an interactive graph.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d6kd2ewduk)

One idea was the inequality $\log(1+x) \ge x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ that comes from the Taylor series expansion, but that doesn't work because the $a$ is in the wrong place.

This looks like something I've seen before and forgotten. Has anyone else seen it before and remembered?

Comment: You can always try to prove the derivative of the difference is positive, so if it is correct at $0$ it must be correct everywhere after.

Comment: Playing around with the interactive graph, I noticed that the inequality does not seem to hold for $a$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 3):

The claim is false:

For $a = 100$:

[image]

Comment: I was about to complain about your graphs.  Then I noticed the log scale...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the graphical evidence, here is why you should not expect the inequality (or something similar) to hold:

If we take $x=a$ (the maximizer of the left side), then the inequality reads
$$
e^{a/2}\leq 1+a^2.
$$
Clearly, this cannot hold for sufficiently large $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @MaoWao's comment and @DavidGStork's answer:

$$e^{x-x^2/2a}=e^{-\frac{1}{2a}(x^2-2ax+a^2)}e^{a/2}=e^{-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2a}}e^{a/2}$$
The maximum of the above expression is at $x=a$ and the maximum value is $e^{a/2}$. At the same $x$, the right hand side is $1+a^2$. But we know that the exponential goes to infinity faster than any polynomial, so there is a value $a_0$ for which the left hand side is larger.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function $f(x) = \ln(1+ ax) - (x-x^2/2a)$ has a local minimum, which has to stay non-negative, in order for the inequality $e^{x-x^2/2a} \le 1+ ax$ to hold for all $x\ge0$.

[image]

The critical value of $a$ can be found by requiring that the local minimum of $f(x)$ is zero, i.e. $f'(x)=f(x) = 0$, leading to the following equations

$$\ln(1+ ax) - (x-x^2/2a) = 0$$
$$ax^2-(a^2-1)x-a(a-1)=0$$

The second equation is quadratic, which allows $x$ to be expressed as a function of $a$. Then, plug $x(a)$ into the first equation, which has to be solved numerically and yields $a\approx 8.4$.

Thus, the inequality $e^{x-x^2/2a} \le 1+ ax$ holds for the following values of $a$,

$$1\le a \le 8.4$$